# Difference between 2 points a circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, voltage, batteries

I am asked to find the voltage difference between points A and B, namely $V_a - V_b$ of the following circuit:

[image: circuit]

I don't exactly know how to approach this however. Is it as simple as going counter clock wise from A to B (since this path doesn't have an opening) and counting the voltage changes, so +20V - 10V? Or am I missing something? Thanks for any help

Comment: Left and bottom batteries voltage can't be read easily (At least, not visible to me)... Could you please specify them?

Comment: Realistically we'd need to include the potential drop in the wires aswell, but yes, they want you to minus the potential from the components from 35v

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you setup the potential-difference equations. From your schematics it follows:

$$\varphi_Y - \varphi_B = +10 \text{ V}$$

$$\varphi_Y - \varphi_A = +20 \text{ V}$$

From this you can easily find what is $\varphi_A - \varphi_B$.

Answer (score 0):

The current runs anticlockwise (from the positive side).Since voltage of two batteries aren't visible (can not read) to me. I am naming them $V_\alpha$ and $V_\beta$ respectively for left and bottom batteries.

[image]

$$V=V_A-V_\alpha$$
$$V_B=V-V_\beta$$

Comment: They are: $V_a = 20V, V_b = 10V$ ! Thanks for your answer regardless!

Answer (score 0):

If you choose point B as a reference point at V = 0, then as you go from B to A the voltage rises by ten and then drops by 20 volts. (Your answer will be negative.)